# search field in a dataview in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, dataview, extjs-mvc

Am trying to put a search field with respect to a data view. There is a toolbar on top of the data view, which consists of a text field. On entering some text in the field, i want to call a search functionality. As of now, i have got hold of the listener to the text field, but the listener is called immediately after the user starts typing something in the text field.

But, what am trying to do is to start the search functionality only when the user has entered at least 3 characters in the text field.How could i do this?

Code below

View

```
var DownloadsPanel = {
            xtype : 'panel',
            border : false,
            title : LANG.BTDOWNLOADS,
            items : [{

                xtype : 'toolbar',
                border : true,
                baseCls : 'subMenu',
                cls : 'effect1',
                dock : 'top',
                height : 25,
                items : [{
                    xtype : 'textfield',
                    name : 'SearchDownload',
                    itemId : 'SearchDownload',
                    enableKeyEvents : true,
                    fieldLabel : LANG.DOWNLOADSF3,
                    allowBlank : true,
                    minLength : 3
                }],
{

                xtype : 'dataview',
                border : false,
                cls : 'catalogue',
                autoScroll : true,
                emptyText : 'No links to display',
                selModel : {
                    deselectOnContainerClick : false
                },
                store : DownloadsStore,
                overItemCls : 'courseView-over',
                itemSelector : 'div.x-item',
                tpl : DownloadsTpl,
                id : 'cataloguedownloads'

            }]
```

Controller:

```
init : function() {

        this.control({
             // reference to the text field in the view
                 '#SearchDownload' :{
                    change: this.SearchDownloads

            }
});

SearchDownloads : function(){
            console.log('Search functionality')

        }
```

**UPDATE 1:** i was able to get hold of the listener after three characters have been entered using the below code:

Controller

```
    '#SearchDownload' :{
                     keyup : this.handleonChange,       
            },

         handleonChange : function(textfield, e, eOpts){

            if(textfield.getValue().length > 3){

                console.log('Three');
            }
    }
```

any guidance or examples on how to perform the search in the store of the data view would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper way would be to subscribe yourself to the **[change](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-change)** event of the field and check if the new value has at least 3 chars before proceeding.

```
'#SearchDownload' :{ change: this.handleonChange }
// othoer code
handleonChange : function(textfield, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ){
      if(newValue.length >= 3){
            console.log('Three');
      }
}
```

Btw. I recommend you to use lowercase and '-' separated names for id's. In your case

```
itemId : 'search-download'
```

**Edit** *apply the filter*

To apply the filter I would use **[filter](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter)** I guess you now the field you want to filter on? Lets pretend `store` is a variable within your controller than you may replace the `console.log()` with

```
this.store.filter('YourFieldName', newValue);
```

Second param can also be a regex using the value like in the example

```
this.store.filter('YourFieldName', new RegExp("/\"+newValue+"$/") );
```

For sure you can also use a Function

```
this.store.filter({filterFn: function(rec) { return rec.get("YourFieldName") > 10; }});
```

Comment: Thank you sra for your comments. have changed it to 'change', and it works perfect:) Also, any guidance about the store search? Can i use the filterBy function

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you so much sra for your answers. Here is what i did, based on your comments

```
filterDownloads : function(val, filterWh){

        if(filterWh == 1){
            var store = Ext.getStore('CatalogueDownloads');
            store.clearFilter();
            store.filterBy(function (r){
                var retval = false;
                var rv = r.get('title');
                var re = new RegExp((val), 'gi');
                retval = re.test(rv);

                if(!retval){
                    var rv = r.get('shortD');
                    var re = new RegExp((val), 'gi');
                    retval = re.test(rv);
                }

                if(retval){
                    return true;
                }

                return retval;
            })




        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think there is an example of exactly what you are trying to achive .. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/form/forum-search.html